# Which way is correct to say "technologies websites" or "technology websites" and why?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, attributive-nouns

Which way is correct to say "technologies websites" or "technology websites" and why?

By a **technology website** I mean a website that contains some information about technologies

Comment: Maybe technological websites?...

Comment: @JustOneMan as of my understanding 
"technological websites" expression is about implementation of the websites
and "technology websites" expression is about content of the websites

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Technology* is being used here as a *noun adjunct* (also called an *attributive noun*), which is to say, a noun being used as an adjective to describe another noun.

When nouns are used this way, they are used in the singular. Hence while a book shop will probably have more than one book, it is still a "book shop", not a "books shop".

This is even the case with nouns like *scissors* and *trousers* that are normally always plural: "Scissor sharpener", "trouser press", etc.

And hence you would want "technology websites" here.

Comment: Ah... interesting - sometimes I find the problem with being a native speaker is you often know which is correct without being able to correctly label **why** ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin it's what makes the study of grammar so interesting; it's not "here's a bunch of rules to follow" but rather "here's a bunch of rules you already follow, without even realising it".

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. However "Technologies websites" is still being used http://bit.ly/2MNDhZl (google gives 24,700 results) . Wondering why:)

Comment: @evgpisarchik Google knows (some) grammar and spelling rules and so is searching for "technology website", "technology websites", "technologies website", etc, as well. In my listing, the only places where "technologies websites" occurs on the first page are for this question, company names ending with Technologies, and a study of tech used by websites, where something else is being said with the two words next to each other.

Comment: @evgpisarchik Can you show a specific search result that uses "technologies websites" in the way you were asking about? "Company Technologies websites" doesn't work, because "Company Technologies" is a proper noun, naming an entity that operates multiple websites. The study preview fragment opens with "We wanted to find out what technologies websites were using," which is using a grammatical construct that happens to put the words next to each other, and is not a use of the two words as one unit.

Comment: And yet you have *sports bar/bra/medicine*, *members area*, *arms race*, *drinks distributor*, etc.

Comment: @userr2684291 _member's area_ contains an apostrophe. There are some exceptions, such as _clothes line_, but mostly the noun must be singular.

Comment: @CJDennis: Usually it's "members' area", with the apostrophe after the "s", since it's an area for all members collectively.

Comment: @V2Blast Thanks for the correction! The point remains that it's incorrect without an apostrophe.

Comment: `"Scissor sharpener", "trouser press", etc` Good point. However, "glasses shop" is an exception here. The singular "glass shop"  implies that the shop sells glass (windows, glassware, ...), not just eyeglasses.

Answer (score 3):

I can't quite decide whether it qualifies as an **[uncountable noun](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/countable-nouns)** or simply an adjective to describe the type of website. Either way, technology remains singular in this usage.

Consider there are many websites, discussing many types of technology - you would still say

> There are many technology websites, covering many aspects of many different technologies.

I've intentionally used *many* each time there - normally you would vary your counts & comparisons, but just to show which aspect we are counting each time

> many websites [not technologies]
>   many aspects

but we close with a countable version,

> many technologies.

Comment: It becomes more clear when you swap "technology" with a noun that is clearly countable: **book** store, **toy** store, **ant** colony. It's neither uncountable nor a (true) adjective, it's a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

Comment: Indeed, though to recognise that, first I would have had to have heard of a noun adjunct before today ;))