# Why it is "A question bank" and not "A questions bank"?

Tags: grammar, compounds, compound-nouns

Why we call it "A **question** bank" or "**Question** bank" in a singular form of "*question*"?

Why it is not "*questions*" in a plural form,
'cause it implies for many questions.. not just one?

Is it sth related to compound-nouns?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which way is correct to say "technologies websites" or "technology websites" and why?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/178634/which-way-is-correct-to-say-technologies-websites-or-technology-websites-and)

Comment: The short answer is "because we don't use plurals when we use a noun like an adjective."  It is a **horse race**, not a *horses race*, a **book store**, not a *books store*, etc.

Comment: But, why we say "clothes shop" and "sports club" in a plural form?
Here, we use nouns as adjectives in a plural form

Comment: That's a good point.  I will say that "clothes shop" does not quite sound like fluent American English, but "sports club" does.  The best explanation I could probably give is that there are multiple *kinds* of sports at a sports club; we often pluralize nouns that would not normally be plural if we mean "multiple kinds of ____", like "I see five **fish**", but speak about "the **fishes** of the Mediterranean."

Comment: I got it, but "question bank" also contains multiple and different kinds/types of question forms.. right?

Comment: Yes, but so does a "book store", and we still say *book* store and not *books* store.  I think the general rule still applies: use the singular unless there is a very specific reason not to.